# How to add custom font on Rails app (version 7)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, ruby-on-rails-7

In development mode the custom fonts (Raleway) are present but it is not reflected in the staging environment. I deployed my app to Heroku.

Added the following command in the application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

Added the font-family in the application.bootstrap.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'raleway-regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: font-url('raleway-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'raleway-semibold';
  src: font-url('raleway-semibold.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'raleway-medium';
  src: font-url('raleway-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

The font files are available in the `my_app/app/assets/fonts` directory.

I created my rails using the command `rails new my_app --javascript esbuild --css bootstrap  --database postgresql`

**Rails version 7**

Comment: If possible can you try adding custom fonts using CDNs?

Comment: Thanks @DeepakKumar, sure I'll consider but is it possible to use the downloaded fonts?

Comment: Yes its possible. Can you try changing font-url to asset_url?
src: asset_url('raleway-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');

Comment: It seems to work also if instead of adding config.assets.paths... you add  //= link_tree ../fonts  to app/assets/config/manifest.js. I think this is a more modern way.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use `url` instead of `font-url`. It works for me. With scss and the same folder configuration.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font-name';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("font-name.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

Rails creates its own font path

```
/assets/font-name-afb238caf5f2396b697d84a32556090b0851e382692f617c6aeaac79e02971a0.ttf
```

Comment: Also of note, the asset pipeline in Rails now throws an error when you enclose the name of the font in single or double quotes in the `src` attribute.  Just enclose it with parens and it should work fine.

Comment: I was getting the below error when trying to use mina to deploy: 
"SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "...32ef36ed15a2e1e": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was '.otf) format("opent'
               on line 19819:106 of stdin
       >> 32ef36ed15a2e1e.otf) format("opentype");"

I had imported a font file into the application.scss.  Once I changed "font-url" to "url" the error went away.  Thanks for this!